# Is there a name for this notion in mathematics?

Tags: combinatorics

So earlier today at lunch someone brought up the fact that Nadal has won 9 out of the last 10 Roland Garros tournaments. For some reason I started thinking that no matter when he lost that one tournament, he must have won at least 5 of those tournaments 5 years in a row.

More generally, if someone loses $k$ out of $n$ games, then they must have won at least $\lceil \frac{n-k}{k+1} \rceil$ games in a row (it seems pretty obvious although I can't prove it, maybe using stars and bars?).

Is there a name for this "minimum" number?

I also know that this number also represents the maximum number of games won in a row, when we try to divide the games into "as similar as possible" winning streaks

Comment: Sounds like the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) but don't you mean $\left\lceil\frac{n-k}{k+1}\right\rceil$ instead of $\left\lceil\frac n{k+1}\right\rceil$?

Comment: No, take for example 11 games with 1 lost. We are assured 6 games in a row. Thanks for the link on pigeonhole, I'm checking it out

Comment: 11 games with 1 lost, e.g., WWWWWLWWWWW.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I jus realized my n was "won games". Thanks